# Json parsing errors at android

Tags: java, android, json

**I want to parse below data but I got a errors when I try other url like this http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/ for the parsing json data I can parsing data,but when I try below code for the parsing I got a below error.**

```
Activity jsonparse.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41b86fb8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-580,162} that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity jsonparse.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41b86fb8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-580,162} that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:218)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
at jsonparse.MainActivity$DownloadJSON.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:58)
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
at jsonparse.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

)

```
 {
        "AllUsersResult":[
            {
                "GroupID":null,
                "ID":1,
                "Password":"1234",
                "Role":null,
                "Username":"admin",
                "customerID":null
            }
        ]

 }
```

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    TextView ver;
    TextView name;
    TextView api;
    Button Btngetdata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://192.168.0.39:8090/TrackBinSvc.svc/AllUsers/admin/1234";

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_OS = "AllUsersResult";
    private static final String TAG_VER = "GroupID";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "Password";
    private static final String TAG_API = "Username";

    JSONArray android = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 new JSONParse().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
         private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vers);
            name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
            api = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.api);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
             pDialog.dismiss();
             try {
                    // Getting JSON Array from URL
                    android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                    for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String api = c.getString(TAG_API);

                    // Adding value HashMap key => value
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_API, api);

                    oslist.add(map);
                    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                            R.layout.list_v,
                            new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.vers,R.id.name, R.id.api});

                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
    }
}
```

JSONParser class

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: please show the exception message ( e.toString())

Comment: I update errors to above

Comment: the error is not in parsing.. It is saying window leaked. see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added

Answer (score 0):

I am suggest you parse data with volley library it is easy to use and also flexible ! [Here is Tutorial link !](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)

Hope this will helps you ! Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Change your JSONParse  class to this..

```
 private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vers);
        name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        api = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.api);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        if(json!=null)
        {
           // Getting JSON Array from URL
                android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String api = c.getString(TAG_API);

                // Adding value HashMap key => value
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_API, api);

                oslist.add(map);

              return oslist;
          }
        //else DATA Not Found or Server not connected

    }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result_list) {
        if(pDialog!=null)
        {
         pDialog.dismiss();
         }

                list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, result_list,
                        R.layout.list_v,
                        new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
                                R.id.vers,R.id.name, R.id.api});

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+result_list.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

                }
     }
}
```

Hope this will help you.